# What tense is this?

Tags: tense

> She felt happy after taking the exam.

What tense used in this sentence ?

Comment: Welcome to ell Hazeem, would you explain more? It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you for the response . I saw this sentence in a book and I didn't know what type of grammar this sentence is ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "type of grammar".  Please [edit] your question. You can [edit] to tell us some examples of "types of grammar".

Comment: It's a declarative sentence.

Answer (score 1):

As a leaner:

Subject: She

Verb: Felt

Complement for the linking verb: Happy

Adverbial clause: after taking the exam

Comment: The adverbial phrase is also a dependent -- Subordinating conjunction: After; Gerund phrase: Taking the exam; ...